# how to install nodejs 0.10.26 from binaries in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am new to linux and am trying to install nodejs latest version with binaries. The solutions I have looked up suggest the installation using apt-get on some private repositories(PPA), which I do not want to do.

So I ran the following commands:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz
mv node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 node-v0.10.26
sudo cp -r node-v0.10.26 /usr/local/src
```

After this, I don't really know what to do. I read an article which suggested created symbolic links, which I am kind of scared to mess up with without knowing the details.

Could you please give me a set of commands to run after this in order to install node with npm? I guess npm should be a part of this binary version.

Comment: check out this shell script: https://github.com/gdbtek/setup-ubuntu/blob/master/cookbooks/node-js/recipes/install.bash

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The best way to install Node.js and have the latest version (or any other version that you prefer, be it LTS or "current") is to download the official binary bundle and uncompress it. A neat way to do it:

```sh
# Use version 0.10.26
$ NODE_VERSION="v0.10.26"

# To use a newer version, for example 6.10.3, use instead:
$ NODE_VERSION="v6.10.3"

$ curl -LO http://nodejs.org/dist/$NODE_VERSION/node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ tar xzf node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ sudo cp -rp node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64 /usr/local/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64 /usr/local/node
```

The basic idea is to move all the contents of the archive into `/usr/local`, then create a symlink in `/usr/local/node` pointing to the most recent version.

For enabling the use of the "node" executable from the command line without referencing the full path (`/usr/local/node/bin/node`), add `/usr/local/node/bin` to your `$PATH` (usually this involves altering the `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file; there's plenty of docs for how to do this).

If you need to update Node.js (suppose it's version 7.10.0), then, just extract the tarball in `/usr/local` and update the symbolic link so it points to the new one. You can then optionally remove the old folder.

**May 2017 update**

As of the "Creators Update", the commands above can now work also on Windows 10 using the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" (via bash). On Ubuntu on Windows 10, after creating the symlink like above, to add the folder to your `$PATH` add `PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"` in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: I wrote this cookbook to install Node-js with latest version for Ubuntu: https://github.com/gdbtek/setup-ubuntu/blob/master/cookbooks/node-js/recipes/install.bash

Comment: Can I not just add /usr/local/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 to $PATH?

Comment: @jackyu you could, but then you'd have to update your $PATH every time you update Node. Symlinks are the easy way to go

Comment: or do not change $PATH and create symlink right in /usr/local/bin (it is usually already in $PATH): /usr/local/bin$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/node-vxxx-linux-x64/bin/node (and the same for npm)

Comment: @IvanRave that would work but you'll "pollute" your /usr/local/bin and future updates will be harder (what if node adds another executable?). also, it may be source of conflict more easily (e.g. another package that you install that decides to add its own node executable)

Comment: @user151841 good question, that you should ask to the maintainers of the distros! My guess is that Node has been evolving too fast; maintainers of distros have issues with this because they need to test every version before it's packaged. Also, Node is younger and it went through lots of major releases (0.8, 0.10, 0.12, 3, 4, 5, 6) in just a few years. Each major release also broke npm deps. Because of that, admins may just prefer to install their own node bins... I hope that now that Node has LTS releases, this changes!

Answer (score 0):

I combined both of these answers for my docker container. I wanted the executable to be in the PATH already without me explicitly doing that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
install_node() {
    NODE_VERSION="v8.3.0"

    curl -# "http://nodejs.org/dist/${NODE_VERSION}/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz" | tar -xz
    cp -pr "node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64" "/usr/local/"
    ln -s "/usr/local/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64" "/usr/local/node"
    ln -s /usr/local/node/bin/* "/usr/local/bin"
    rm -rf "node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64"
}
install_node
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the binary anywhere and use **update-alternatives** command which maintain symbolic links determining default commands for example this is on my laptop.

first i extract my node node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz on /mnt/e/WSL_Ubuntu/Downloads/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/ folder :

```
xxxx@xxxxPC:.../WSL_Ubuntu/Downloads$ tar xvf node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
xxxx@xxxxPC:.../WSL_Ubuntu/Downloads$ cd node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/
```

then update-alternatives --install :

```
xxxx@xxxxPC:.../node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin$ sudo update-alternatives --install /home/wira/.local/bin/node node\
> /mnt/e/WSL_Ubuntu/Downloads/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/node 60
update-alternatives: using /mnt/e/WSL_Ubuntu/Downloads/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/node to provide /home/wira/.local/bin/node (node) in auto mode
```

Now i use the node on terminal

```
xxxx@xxxxPC:.../node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin$ node --version
v10.16.3
```

You should also update-alternatives --install on npm binaries.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is still a cleaner way

```
NODE_VERSION="v6.7.0"

# Download
curl -LO http://nodejs.org/dist/$NODE_VERSION/node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz

# uncompress
tar xzf node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz

# selective copy
cp -R ./node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/* /usr/local/bin
cp -R ./node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/lib/* /usr/local/lib
cp -R ./node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/include/* /usr/local/include
cp -R ./node-$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/share/* /usr/local/share
```

Node should be working now

```
$ node -e 'console.log("HI")'
HI
```

Hope it helps

Comment: See comments to my answer above. This is not really cleaner because it may be cause of conflicts if you then install Node.js from a package (e.g. as a dependency of another package). I'd strongly recommend keeping the node binaries in another directory.

Comment: @Qualcuno Your proposal may cause exactly the same conflicts as mine.

APT/RPM packages are not meant to be installed into /usr/local/* but /usr/bin, /usr/lib, /usr/share and so on.

So BOTH answers may cause the same effects if system packages depend on a packaged NodeJS version

Comment: the problem is not with breaking packages you'll install, but rather with breaking your Node.js production application running on your server. You don't want to risk that a malformed package overwrites your Node interpreter on your server.